# how to show number of users by age group in chart control in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

how to show number of users by age group in chart control in Asp.net MVC?

Here is the logic to get age group and number of users in each age group, but how to use this in chart control is making me confuse. Please suggest whether I need to add another class or need to modify LINQ query by using group operation.

```
 public List<AgeVM> getuserAge()
            {
                List<AgeVM> listAgeVM = new List<AgeVM>();
                int countteen = 0;
                int countYoung = 0;
                int countMedioker = 0;
                int countSenior = 0;
                var res = from a in _Registrationrepository.GetAll()
                          select new
                          {
                              age = a.DOB,
                              name = a.FirstName,

                          };
                foreach (var item in res)
                {

                    AgeVM ageVM = new AgeVM();

                    var day = item.age.Day;
                    var month = item.age.Month;
                    var year = item.age.Year;
                    var currentDay = System.DateTime.Now.Day;
                    var currentMonth = System.DateTime.Now.Month;
                    var currentYear = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
                    if (day > currentDay)
                    {
                        currentDay = currentDay + 30;
                        currentMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                    }
                    if (month > currentMonth)
                    {
                        currentMonth = currentMonth + 12;
                        currentYear = currentYear - 1;
                    }
                    string agegrp;
                    var realAge = currentYear - year;
                    if (realAge < 18 && realAge > 13)
                    {
                        agegrp = "teen";
                        countteen++;
                    }
                    if (realAge < 26 && realAge > 18)
                    {
                        agegrp = "Young";
                        countYoung++;
                    }
                    if (realAge < 45 && realAge > 26)
                    {
                        agegrp = "Medioker";
                        countMedioker++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        agegrp = "Senior Citizen";
                        countSenior++;
                    }

                    ageVM.AgeGroupName = agegrp;


                    listAgeVM.Add(ageVM);
                }

                return listAgeVM;

            }


            public ActionResult AgeUserColumnChart()
            {
                ArrayList xValue = new ArrayList();
                ArrayList yValue = new ArrayList();
                var res = getuserAge();

                foreach (var item in res)
                {
                    xValue.Add(item.AgeGroupName);
                  //here yValue should come how to do that???
                }

                new Chart(width: 500, height: 300, theme: ChartTheme.Yellow)
                    .AddTitle("Age wise")
                    .AddSeries(chartType: "column", xValue: xValue,
                    yValues: yValue).Write("bmp");


                return null;
            }
```

here is my ViewModel

```
public class AgeVM
    {
        public string AgeGroupName { get; set; }
        public int NoofUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

please help me to save my day.

Comment: What you want in `yValue`? are you trying to achieve `yValue.Add(item.NoofUsers )` in foreach loop? where you have added comment `
                  //here yValue should come how to do that???`

Comment: yes the no of users related to that age group .like suppose i have 4 teen users and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can make `getuserAge()` function easy and clear by using dictionary, define `AgeGroupName` as key with four constants "teen", "Young"...**

iterate through each record and increment value of respective key by one. At the end of loop you will get key as a `AgeGroupName` and value as `NoofUsers`.

```
   public List<AgeVM> getuserAge()
        {
            List<AgeVM> listAgeVM = new List<AgeVM>();
            Dictionary<string, int> temp = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            temp.Add("teen", 0);
            temp.Add("Young", 0);
            temp.Add("Medioker", 0);
            temp.Add("Senior Citizen", 0);
            var res = from a in _Registrationrepository.GetAll()
                      select new
                      {
                          age = a.DOB,
                          name = a.FirstName,

                      };
            foreach (var item in res)
            {

                AgeVM ageVM = new AgeVM();
               //Write separate function to calculate age.                
                string agegrp;
                var realAge = currentYear - year;
                if (realAge < 18 && realAge > 13)
                {
                    temp["teen"]++;
                }
                if (realAge < 26 && realAge > 18)
                {
                    temp["Young"]++;
                }
                if (realAge < 45 && realAge > 26)
                {
                    temp["Medioker"]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp["Senior Citizen"]++;
                }
            }

  //Now outside foreach loop iterate through each key, value pair of dictionary and assing key to `AgeGroupName` and value to `NoofUsers` property

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> item in temp)
{

       ageVM.AgeGroupName = item.Key;
       ageVM.NoofUsers = item.Value;
}

            return listAgeVM;

        }
```

---

This is not all code, but I gave you an idea. How you can simplify your code.

Comment: yes,that is the problem i know,but how to do that  for different age groups .

Comment: @SachinSingh, I updated my answer. Please look at it, if it doesn't help please let me know

Comment: I did not get your comment; but my answer was to  get count of youngsters, meniokers etc and assigning it to respective property

Comment: Thanks @PrasadTelkikar ,it really helped.